# how to change project name by grails custom script

Tags: grails, gradle, gant

I want to write a script to change grails project's name.

need to modify:

1. **.project** :  Vote  -> NewName
2. **application.properties** :  app.name=AMP -> app.name=NewName

could anyone show me an example or link of match doc?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but there is an [ant.propertyFile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html).  You might be able to do something like...

```
ant.propertyfile(
   file:"/projectPath/application.properties") {
      entry(key:"app.name", value:'foo')
   }
)
```